# Bind DependencyProperty of Usercontrol in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, datacontext

I need ListBox with my UserControl listed in it. My UserControl has TextBox. So I want to display property of List's subitem in UserControl's textBox. I have tried  a lot of options with DataContext and ElementName - it just doesn`t work. I just stucked on it. The only way to make it work is to remove DataContext binding of UserControl to itself and change Item Property name so it matches to DependencyProperty name - but I need to reuse my control in different viewmodels with different entities so it is almost not possible  to use the approach.

Interesting thing is that if I change my UserControl to Textbox and bind Text property of it - everything works. What the difference between Textbox and my UserControl?

So let me just show my code.
I have simplified the code to show only essential:

Control XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestControl.MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Control CS:

```
    public partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } 
        public string Text
        {
            get { 
                return (string)this.GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { 
                this.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), new propertyMetadata(""));
}
```

Window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestControl.MainWindow"
        Name="_windows"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestControl"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <Grid Name="RootGrid">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=_windows, Path=MyList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <local:MyControl Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            _list = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            _list.Add(new Item("Sam"));
            _list.Add(new Item("App"));
            _list.Add(new Item("H**"));
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private ObservableCollection<Item> _list;

        public ObservableCollection<Item> MyList
        {
            get { return _list;}
            set {}
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public Item(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }

        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty big gotcha in XAML.  The problem is that when you do this in the user control:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

You change its data context, so that in this line:

```
<local:MyControl Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
```

The runtime will now attempt to resolve "Name" on the instance of "MyControl", instead of on the inherited data context (ie, the view model).  (Confirm this by checking the Output window -- you should see a binding error to that effect.)

You can get around this by, instead of setting the user control's data context that way, using a `RelativeSource` binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestControl.MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200"
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
        />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: "This is a pretty big gotcha in XAML." - thats quite the understatement, has cost me many hours to finally find the answer